# Showing unexpected values in Power BI charts

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Please find my expected result below

[image: chart expected]

But I am getting result as below

[image: chart obtained]

where I have choosed Order Id from orders table and Product Id from Order Items tables and I have used below measure
order_to_orderitem = CALCULATE(SUM('Order Items'[Unit Price]),USERELATIONSHIP(orders[key12],'Order Items'[key12]))

Note: key12 is merged column of Order Id and Product Id in both orders and Order Items table

I have a datamodel as shown below

[image: Power BI datamodel]

I have given a relationship as shown below

[image: Power BI datamodel Relationship]

It has been created as shown below where From Table is Order Items and To Table is orders whereas while creating I have given orders as From Table and Order Items as To Table

[image: Power BI Realtionship details]

Orders table:

[image: Orders]

Order Items table:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your dataset? Where/how are products 3 and 4 defined?

Comment: @JoaoLeal edited my post by adding dataset

Comment: Hi @sheetal those 2 tables don't seem to relate/be the same results as the example above.

Comment: @JoaoLeal sorry, updated them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all rows from the orders table and the matching rows from the Order Items table you can just create a new table with LEFT JOIN.

```
NewTable = NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ('orders', 'Order Items' )
```

(the function works for the tables that don't have the same column names). To get this table check "Show items with no data" for the first column.
[image: Final table]